How to implement concurrent/parallel listen on a WebSocket and a local process?
I'm currently developing a system that can simulate a CLI interaction in a web browser. I do this by receiving user/client input through a websocket, and passing that input into a docker container subprocess via TTY. I then listen from the TTY for output from the docker, and then send that output to the websocket for the client.
Here's my implementation so far, I'm using FastAPI as a backend and I'm using FastAPI's websocket, and sorry for the extremely smelly and spaghetti code, it's meant to be temporary code as I learn the best way to implement a CLI interaction and how to implement this functionality properly.
@router.websocket("/interactv1")
async def interact_with_instance(websocket: WebSocket, token: Annotated[str | None, Cookie()] = None, db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    pty, tty = pypty.openpty()

    #TODO: move this instance call to the html page using js instead of calling it here
    if not token:
        print("no token")
        websocket.close()
        return

    user_id = utils.read_token(token).get("id")

    instance = crud.get_lab_instance_by_user(db, user_id)

    # subprocess.Popen(['docker', 'run', '-it', '--rm', '--privileged', '-e', 'DISPLAY', '-v', '/tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix', '-v', '/lib/modules:/lib/modules', 'iwaseyusuke/mininet', '--name'], stdin=tty, stdout=tty, stderr=tty)
    subprocess.Popen(['docker', 'exec', '-it', str(instance.id), 'bash'], stdin=tty, stdout=tty, stderr=tty)

    await manager.connect(websocket)

    error_msg = f"Error response from daemon: No such container: {str(instance.id)}"

    container_doesnt_exist = False

    last_message = ""

    while True:
        print('listening from docker')
        r, _, _ = select.select([pty], [], [], 0.1)
        if pty in r:
            print('data from docker')
            data = os.read(pty, 10240)
            print("message = ")
            print(data.decode())
            print(f"error_msg = {error_msg}")
            if data.decode().strip() == error_msg.strip():
                container_doesnt_exist = True
                break
            last_message = data.decode()
        else:
            break

    if container_doesnt_exist:
        print("container doesn't exist")
        subprocess.Popen(['docker', 'run', '--name', str(instance.id), '-it', '--rm', '--privileged', '-e', 'DISPLAY', '-v', '/tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix', '-v', '/lib/modules:/lib/modules', 'iwaseyusuke/mininet'], stdin=tty, stdout=tty, stderr=tty)
        while True:
            r, _, _ = select.select([pty], [], [], 0.1)
            if pty in r:
                data = os.read(pty, 10240)
                print(data.decode())
            else:
                break

    await websocket.send_text(last_message)

    while True:
        print('listening from websocket')
        data = await websocket.receive_text()
        data = data + "\n"
        print(data.encode())
        os.write(pty, data.encode())

        r, _, _ = select.select([pty], [], [], 0.1)
        output = os.read(pty, 10240)

        if data[0:2] == "cd":
            cut = len(data) + 2
            output = output[cut:]
            await websocket.send_text(output.decode())

        while True:
            print('listening from docker')
            r, _, _ = select.select([pty], [], [], 0.1)
            if pty in r:
                print('data from docker')
                data = os.read(pty, 10240)
                print(data)
                await websocket.send_text(data.decode())
            else:
                print('breaking from listening docker')
                break

For the most part, this code works in essence. However, it's currently implemented in a way that I can't have the server to listen from both the websocket and the TTY output. It's currently working by first listening for user input from the websocket, and then asynchronously waits for TTY to finish sending outputs (which is determined by a hard coded time limit), and then hands the control/listening back to the websocket. This implementation is inefficient because I have to hard code to take into account interactions that might not necessarily return an output in the set determined amount of time, and I also can't implement things such as CTRL+C keyboard interruption on the frontend because the server won't be listening for inputs from the websocket while its listening for output from the TTY. How do I implement a method that can have the server listen from both the websocket and the TTY at the same time? I would also be grateful if there's a better idea or way to simulate a CLI interaction on a web browser.

You might find this answer and this answer helpful as well.
